# local Storage not working properly in game using js and html5

Tags: javascript, html, save, local-storage

```
<!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
   <script>
    var cash = 1;
    function start(){
         setInterval('add()',1000)
      }


 function add(){
   cash = cash + 1;
   localStorage.setItem('cash',cash)
  document.getElementById('cash').innerHTML = cash;

  }

  function save(){
   localStorage.setItem('cash',cash);

   }

  function load(){
  cash = localStorage.getItem('cash');

  }
  </script>

 <body onLoad="start()">
<p id="lvl">lvl</p>
<p id="cash">cash</p>
<button type="button" onClick="add()">clickMe</button>
<button type="button" onClick="save()">Save</button>
<button type="button" onClick="load()">load</button>
 </body>
  </html>
```

When I click save then load it always appears like 4111 and the 1's keep going just test it on jsfiddle.net since I cannot explain it. But what I want it to do is store the users currents cash when saved then when the load button is clicked bring back the user's cash that he/she had before and keep counting up.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 cash = parseInt(cash,10) + 1;
```

instead of,

```
cash = cash + 1;
```

Ref:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Ref: http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/localstorage.md.html

Comment: woah you fixed the glitch. And I've just fixed the saving problem so now I can move on and keep coding :D thanks really appreciate it.